# htmlbox 4.0 set textarea with value

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using texteditor htmlbox 4.0 inisde my page , when i press a button i want my texteditor to be set with a value.

i can't get to set it's value.

how can this be done?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTMLBox set_text() method
Initialize your HTML box as
     hb_TxtArea = $("#txt_notes")..htmlbox({});
and then use hb_TxtArea,set_text('') on your button click.